# what is wrong with my MineSweeper dot java

Tags: java, arrays, minesweeper

I'm building the logic behind minesweeper but not the actual game, where I'm simply just setting up a 4*4 mineField array with default value=0, and randomly generating 4 bombs in it with value=1. my problem is with my checkBomb() method where it's supposed to take on each slot in the array and check all of it's 8 neighboring slots and itself for value 1 ,like this

```
[ ][ ][ ]

[ ][x][ ]

[ ][ ][ ]
```

and count how many bombs are there and this number is stored in a "parallel array" which is then showed on screen.

now I'm able to create the field with 4 randomly generated bombs as with the following code:
    public class MineSweeper {

```
public static int[][] afterCheck=new int[4][4];
public static int[][] mineField=new int[4][4];
public static int bombNumber=4;



public static  void setBombs()
{

    //bombNumber variable will decide the number of loops
    for(int i=0;i<bombNumber;)
    {
        int firstRandom=(int)(Math.random()*4);
        int secondRandom=(int)(Math.random()*4);
        if(mineField[firstRandom][secondRandom]== 0)
            {
                mineField[firstRandom][secondRandom]=1;
                i++;

            }
```

but as for the checkBomb() method so far I've come up with two different codes but none works. 
code1:
   public static void checkBombs()
    {

```
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        int counter=0;
        try{
        for(int y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            if (mineField[i][y + 1] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i][y - 1] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i - 1][y] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i - 1][y + 1] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i - 1][y - 1] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i + 1][y] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i + 1][y + 1] == 1)
                counter++;
            if (mineField[i + 1][y - 1] == 1)
                counter++;


            afterCheck[i][y] = counter;
        }
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }



}
```

the second code:

```
public static void checkBombs()
{

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        int counter=0;
        try{
        for(int y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
           for(int a=i-1;a<i+1;a++)
            {
                for (int b=y-1;b<y+1;b++)
                {
                    if(mineField[a][b]==1)
                        counter++;


                }


            }
            */

            afterCheck[i][y] = counter;
        }
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }



}
```

I need some help u guys.

Comment: Stop catching and ignoring exceptions: they tell you what and where the bug in the code is, and you deliberately choose to ignore them.

Comment: I didn't realize it was bad practice(if that's what you mean)...for me i was trying to ignore the .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException generated by checking the slots on the edges.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, you also ignore all the cells that are checked subsequently, even if they are not out of bounds.

Comment: The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException signals a bug in your code: you're going over the bounds of an array. Catching the exception and hiding it as if it wasn't thrown won't fix the bug. It will only make it harder to diagnose. What you're doing is basically identical to disabling all the warning signs and sounds in your car, and then complaining you don't know why it won't start anymore. So now you know *what* the problem is. The stack trace also tells you *where* the problem is.

Comment: so when an exception is thrown, which is bound to happen, the whole thing is just ignored, right? which explains why the array is all zeros.

Comment: this may be a newbie question, but does that mean I have to write different methods for the different categories of slots?  for ex. top edge, lower edge, left and right?

Comment: An exception like this one is not bound to happen. It only happens because the code has a bug that needs to be fixed. Just make sure, before accessing an index in an array, that this index is valid.

Comment: @Tom There are two arrays: one for bomb placement, the other for neighboring bomb count. The one for bomb placement should actually be a `boolean` array.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh right, he's writing into a different array. Missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a method which safely handles the edges of the board:

```
int bombCount(int i, int j) { 
  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= mineField.length || j >= mineField[i].length)
    return 0;
  return mineField[i][j];
}
```

Then you can use your second version, with for-loops, to sum up the neighboring bomb count by replacing

```
mineField[i][j]
```

with

```
bombCount(i, j)
```

and you can also eliminate all the if-ology there, just use

```
counter += bombCount(i,j);
```

Just for interest, a "bad practice", but *correct*, equivalent of the method above would be

```
int bombCount(int i, int j) { 
  try { return mineField[i][j]; }
  catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException _) { return 0; }
}
```

The difference between the above and your code is that the exception is caught individually for each array access, whereas your way short-circuits the rest of the evaluation upon hitting the first off-the-edge case.

Finally, as a side note, these days HotSpot has optimizations up its sleeve for the bad practice variant so the idiom would actually not hurt performance very much. It would just be frowned upon by most Java experts.